# Scanner throwing java.util.NoSuchElementException when input is taken

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, nosuchelementexception

This code below throws `NoSuchElementException` in the function `aVeryBigSum`. 
PS: This is task from hackerrank so I can only modify the code in function: `aVeryBigSum`.

This function takes the following inputs: `n` which is the number of elements in an array to be added, and the elements of array.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.security.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Solution {

    // Complete the aVeryBigSum function below.
    static long aVeryBigSum(long[] ar) {
        int n, sum = 0;
        Scanner read = new Scanner(System.in);
        n = read.nextInt();
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            sum += read.nextLong();
        return sum;
    }

    private static final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedWriter bufferedWriter
                = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(System.getenv("OUTPUT_PATH")));

        int arCount = scanner.nextInt();
        scanner.skip("(\r\n|[\n\r\u2028\u2029\u0085])?");

        long[] ar = new long[arCount];

        String[] arItems = scanner.nextLine().split(" ");
        scanner.skip("(\r\n|[\n\r\u2028\u2029\u0085])?");

        for (int i = 0; i < arCount; i++) {
            long arItem = Long.parseLong(arItems[i]);
            ar[i] = arItem;
        }

        long result = aVeryBigSum(ar);

        bufferedWriter.write(String.valueOf(result));
        bufferedWriter.newLine();

        bufferedWriter.close();

        scanner.close();
    }
}
```

**Output:**
[image]

Comment: why is your n there of type int, when the method expects a long?

Comment: Yeah that was a mistake too :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you reading from `Scanner` in your `aVeryBigSum` method?

Just loop through `ar` argument and calculate sum.

```
static long aVeryBigSum(long[] ar) {
    long _sum = 0;
    for(int i=0; i < ar.length; i++)
        sum += ar[i];
    return _sum;
}
```

Comment: Explanation: As the input has already been read from the Scanner object in `main()` method. There is no more element available in the buffer to read, that's why you are getting this exception.

You only need to deal with the `ar` argument that is passed to your `aVeryBigSum(long[] ar)` method.

Comment: It is the requirement of the question. Even if I don't read the elements, I'll still have to read the number of elements and that's where the exception is throwing.

Comment: Actually you were right! it worked!! I removed scanner from the function. I didn't even take input for number of elements. But I still don't understand why the exception was thrown... is it because there are two objects of Scanner using same input stream?

Answer (score 0):

```
static long aVeryBigSum(long[] ar) {
    int n;
    Long sum = 0;
    Scanner read = new Scanner(System.in);
    n = read.nextInt();
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        sum += read.nextLong();
    return sum;
}
```

its working fine for me if you  change: int n;
    long sum=0; in existing code and try.

output:2
1 2

5
1000000001
1000000002
1000000003
1000000004
1000000005
5000000015